# Complete categories are cocomplete?

Tags: category-theory, duality-theorems

I've read in a paper and on wikipedia that any (small) category is complete if and only if it is cocomplete. 
Now obviously if one shows that complete$\implies$cocomplete, then it's easy to conclude from there, but I have no idea why that would be true. 
Could anyone care to explain it to me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true in general for a given category $C$. On the other hand, note that $\mathbf{Set}^{C^{op}}$, $is$ complete and cocomplete, and that the Yoneda Lemma provides an embedding $\ y \colon C \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}^{C^{op}}. $  That is,  $C$ can be "enlarged" to a category that is complete and cocomplete.

Comment: Even for small categories ?

Comment: $C$ should be locally small otherwise $yc:C^{op}\to \bf {Set}$  does not make sense.

Comment: No I meant : is the "theorem" not true for small categories ?

Comment: it's even true if $C$ is only $locally$ small.

Comment: I'm not talking about the Yoneda Lemma

Comment: Any complete small category is a preorder so it is also cocomplete.

Comment: You should delete this answer. It's not addressing the question that was asked.

Comment: I actually tried to delete it when I realized that the OP was talking about small categories only, but apparently accepted answers can't be deleted.

Answer (score 5):

The point is that a small complete category is a complete preorder. 
See [nlab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/complete+small+category).

Answer (score 0):

The partial ordered class of sets has all suprema, but not all infima, since it lacks a largest element. Hence, its dual category is complete and not cocomplete.